# OpenShift Database Host Value?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hosting, openshift

I'm trying to install Infinite WP on Openshift, so far, I have uploaded the source files. But, when I was on the installation page, it asked a database host, username, and password. I have the username and password, but I don't know what to put in the database host box. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple hours of playing around with OpenShift, I solved my problem. After you install phpMyAdmin, go to the web interface. When it asks you for a username and password, look at the instructions at the top of the pop-up window and it should include an Ip address. Enter that as the database host during the IWP installation screen and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OPENSHIFT__DB_HOST variable for host value. 
Openshift have given different variables for connection : https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/adding-a-database.html